# make -B always prints "is up to date" for a shell task

Tags: gnu-make

Consider this Makefile

```
test.txt: foo.bar
        $(shell grep ^hello $< >$@)
```

To test it, one needs to create a file `foo.bar` containing, e.g.,

```
hello
hello 2
```

`make` always prints

```
make: 'test.txt' is up to date.
```

This happens even when the file `test.txt` is absent. In this case make runs correctly and creates `test.txt`, but still prints the above message. Even using `make -B` gives the same message.

I am using GNU Make 4.2.1.

Why is this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because it actually is an empty recipe, so there's nothing to run.

`$(shell)` function is evaluated upon Makefile recipe parsing and its output is considered as recipe contents. It happens that this statement generates an output file as a byproduct, but the statement's output is empty, therefore `make` has nothing to do and concludes that target is up to date. In fact it would always say so if the recipe turns out to be empty:

```
$ ls
Makefile  foo.bar
$ cat Makefile
test.txt: foo.bar
        $(info Making $@ from $<)
$ make
Making test.txt from foo.bar
make: 'test.txt' is up to date.
$ ls
Makefile  foo.bar
```

Note that above example did not create `test.txt`, `make` just concluded that it ran the (empty) recipe to update it, so now it is up to date.

In order to run it correctly, you should drop the `$(shell)` function altogether. `make`'s recipes are already invoked in a shell:

```
$ cat Makefile
test.txt: foo.bar
        grep ^hello $< >$@
$ make
grep ^hello foo.bar >test.txt
$ make
make: 'test.txt' is up to date.
$ make -B
grep ^hello foo.bar >test.txt
$ ls
Makefile  foo.bar  test.txt
```